# WP_List_Table add custom bulk actions

Tags: wp-list-table

Is it possible to add a bulk action to an existing WP_List_Table object?

Quforms uses `class Quform_Entry_List_Table extends WP_List_Table`

I would like to add a custom bulk_action to their Entries admin page, but I do not want to customize their commercial plugin.  I can get the bulk action added to the selector using `add_filter('bulk_actions-forms_page_quform.entries','e2QBR_register_resend_action');`
but, I cannot find any way to hook to the "Apply" button.  `add_filter('handle_bulk_actions-forms_page_quform.entries', 'e2QBR_Bulk_Action_Handler',10,3);` does nothing, because this is a WP_List_Table.

If this is possible, I would really appreciate a URL or code snippet to get me started.

Comment: You can hook your callback `e2QBR_Bulk_Action_Handler` to any early admin hooks like `admin_action_<action>`. So if you add a bulk action named `foo_bar`, then you can hook you callback to `admin_action_foo_bar`. And in your callback, you'd probably want to send the user back to the previous page. (`wp_redirect( 'URL' ); exit;`).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately, this won't work with Quforms plugin.  They appear to be capturing and altering the `[ Apply ]` button click.  I put several error_log() statements to record state and variables. At no time does the back-end ever get to my function. At no time does it ever get the value of the bulk actions selection.   .. Oh well ..  I'll try to reach out to their development staff.